# Excel macro to compare values

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, compare, cell

I need your help 
I wanted to know is there any vba script to get my job done easier
As of now I'm working with IF and AND conditions
I would like to have it changed with a macro
So I can selected the range and covert to "1" and "0"

All I need to do is compare the values in the every column with the right answer in 1 cell of every column
Mark 1 for match 0 for no match

Thank you
Any help will be great full

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like the VBA code below. The Code is dynamic so your table can vary in size. You can set the start column of your data table (Candidate R1) in:

```
Const ColStart As Integer = 2
```

and also the end column (Candidate R10)

```
Const ColEnd As Integer = 11
```

**VBA Code**

```
Sub FormulaToCompare()

Dim lrow As Integer
Dim lrowCandidate As Integer
Dim NextFree As Integer

Const ColStart As Integer = 2 'Which column your data table start at (R1). R1 is in Column B = Column 2
Const ColEnd As Integer = 11 'Which column your data table start at (R1). R1 is in Column B = Column 2


lrowCandidate = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last row of the Column Candidate (Column A)

Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, ColEnd)).Offset(lrowCandidate + 2, 0).Value = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, ColEnd)).Value 'Copy Headers to 2nd table
Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(lrowCandidate, 1)).Offset(lrowCandidate + 2, 0).Value = Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(lrowCandidate, 1)).Value 'Copy Candidate numbers to 2nd table

For i = ColStart To ColEnd 'Loop from start column to end column of data, Column i
    NextFree = Range(Cells(1, i), Cells(Rows.Count, i)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row - 1 'Find the last row starting from above in Column i EXCLUDING 2nd table.
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row 'Find the last row starting from above in Column i INCLUDING 2nd table.
        For j = 3 To NextFree 'Loop from row 3 (2 rows are headers, therefore we start at row 3) to last row excluding 2nd table
            Cells(lrow + j - 2, i).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(AND(R[-" & NextFree + 2 & "]C<>0, R[-" & NextFree + 2 & "]C=R1C),1,0)" 'Find the cell to paste the formula into. The formula is dynamic
        Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi wizhi thank you for the solution, you made my day easier.. its very helpful as guys like you guide the people in need of knowledge, great work keep up,

Comment: Wizi is there any way that i can append the changed in same table, without generating a new table below as your macro is doing a great job, ----all my team mates convey their thanks to you

Comment: I would really appreciate if you mark the answer as solved [(Mark Answer as Approved)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juCwS.png). It help other people to know the question is solved and gives some credit point to the person who took the time to answered. I will wait for it ;)

Comment: Thank you for the kind words. Yes it should be possible, how do you want it?Referring to the example in your question, at which row do you want to append the table? Do you want the table to directly start at 13 :)?

Comment: Hi wizhi thank you, the problem is solved by your knowledge, as you directed i have marked, this as solved, thank you again, cheers

Comment: Thank you!!! Much appreciated.

Comment: To replace your new values in the old table you could add this code after "`Next i`": `Range(Cells(3, ColStart), Cells(lrowCandidate, ColEnd)).Offset(lrowCandidate + 2, 0).Copy 'Copy new table
Range(Cells(3, ColStart), Cells(lrowCandidate, ColEnd)).Offset(lrowCandidate + 2, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'paste new table

Rows(ColStart + 1 & ":" & lrowCandidate + 4).EntireRow.Delete 'Delete the old table`